# It's possible change the Acitivity's Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

I would create an Activity on which there are two choices and when I click on the choice my activity have a layout if I click on the other choice I have another layout? Anyone can suggest me? My question is only information before to start!

Comment: your question shows how little research / effort you've done. Answering it takes time and effort and you should try again once you have a more complete overview of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Yes just call `setContentView` to set or change the layout.

Comment: @JigneshJain - Why is this not an answer? It tells OP exactly what to do to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: @TedHopp, agreed. But since it shows as little concern/interest as the question, it can be settled that it is a "low quality" answer